# Observable HttpEvent is not assignable to type Observable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm calling REST API from my **angular** app, I've written below service class in **typescript**. I want to call different **url** and pass different **headers** based on the environment selection.
**For example:** if environment is **dev** then `userURL` value should be `http://mydomain-dev.com/users/` and **header** should be `devHttpOptions`, similarly for **QA** - the `userURL` should be `http://mydomain-qa.com/users/` and **header** should be `qaHttpOptions` and so on.

I've written below **switch case** statement, based on **environment** value, I'm deciding which **url** and **header** should be assigned.

But I'm getting below compile time error when I pass `this.httpOptions` in **get** method - `this.http.get<User[]>(this.userURL, this.httpOptions)`

```
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<User[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
  Type 'HttpEvent<User[]>' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.
    Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(
```

**Please find my code below:**

**UserService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./user";
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    userURL: any;
    httpOptions: any;
    devHttpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('dev-xxxx:yyyy')
        })
    };

    qaHttpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('qa-xxxx:yyyy')
        })
    };

    prodHttpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('prod-xxxx:yyyy')
        })
    };


    getUsers(environment): Observable<User[]> {

        console.log(environment);
        switch (environment) {
            case 'dev':
                this.userURL = 'http://mydomain-dev.com/users/';
                this.httpOptions = this.devHttpOptions;
                break;
            case 'qa':
                this.userURL = 'http://mydomain-qa.com/users/';
                this.httpOptions = this.qaHttpOptions;
                break;
            case 'prod':
                this.userURL = 'http://mydomain-prod.com/users/';
                this.httpOptions = this.prodHttpOptions;
                break;

        }
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userURL, this.httpOptions);
    }

}
```

Could you please help me with this issue. Appreciated your help in advance!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http headers is not found on the httpsOptions variable of type any so you can use it directly this way. You should do something like this:

```
return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userURL, {
        headers: this.httpOptions?.headers
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see all of the overloads for `get()` here:

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

It doesn't know that `httpOptions` is an object so it is using the wrong overload. When you use `any` it defaults to the first overload that matches `get<T>` which returns `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`. If you declare an object that does not have an `observe` property on it, it'll use the overload you want, since `observe` is an optional property on that one, while it is required on the others.

Initialize `httpOptions` as an object or declare it as an object.

```js
httpOptions = {};
```

or

```js
httpOptions: Object;
```

---

Alternatively you can put `observe: 'body'` on the options object. That will explicitly select the overload you want.

```js
  httpOptions: any;

  getUsers(environment) {
    ...
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userURL, {
      ...this.httpOptions,
      observe: 'body',
    });
  }
```